# Why doesn't my second form show up?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I made a timer, but when I press a button nothing happens.

My code is:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Instellingen form = new Instellingen();
        form.Show();
    }
```

Instellingen.cs code:

```
public partial class Instellingen : Form
{
    public Instellingen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("text", "text");
        }
    }
}
```

The button3 event doesn't even fire (confirmed by adding a breakpoint, it doesn't get there)

Comment: this code is fine. Show us the code for your form Instellingen

Comment: This should work. Are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if the button's event realy connected to the method `button3_Click`.
2. Put a breakpoint in the first line of `button3_Click` and check if the code get there.

Comment: So please reset (clear and set) your button's event to this function then check again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your button's click event is `button3_Click`.  Probably your button's click event is empty.

Comment: @Wouter use debugger and breakpoints. Why are you sure that event handler is invoked?